# What is the underlying Math/Equation of Excel RATE() function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Principal= 200000
Fees= 1000
Nper= 360
Pmt= 1074
Pv= 199000

If I use the Excel Rate Function then it gives me the value =RATE(360,1074,199000)*12=5.044%

I would like to know the equation/internal math for this function.

Comment: This is just Internal Rate of Return.  Look in any Finance text book.  HP Financial Calculators use the same thing. '

Comment: Formula and Calculation for IRR
The formula and calculation used to determine this figure are as follows:

NPV = SUM (1 to t) (C at Time T / (1 +IRR)   all - C at the start.
0=NPV= 
t=1
∑
T
​
  
(1+IRR) 
t
 
C 
t
​
 
​
 −C 
0
​
 
where:
C 
t
​
 =Net cash inflow during the period t
C 
0
​
 =Total initial investment costs
IRR=The internal rate of return
t=The number of time periods
​

Answer (score 1):

Please see [IRR](https://https:/https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irr.asp#:%7E:text=The%20internal%20rate%20of%20return,same%20formula%20as%20NPV%20does.)

> The internal rate of return (IRR) is a metric used in financial
> analysis to estimate the profitability of potential investments. IRR
> is a discount rate that makes the net present value (NPV) of all cash
> flows equal to zero in a discounted cash flow analysis.
>
> IRR calculations rely on the same formula as NPV does.

Formula and Calculation for IRR
The formula and calculation used to determine this figure are as follows:

NPV= [ ∑​ CT/(1+IRR) raised to power t ] - CSTART